# Draw graphics to look like this

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, java-3d

I'm wondering how can I render lines and textboxes and labels etc, to look like this:

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Because I am doing something similar and I need to represent the communication among different devices.

I'd only need to render the images of the textboxes, horizontal lines, etc. In other words, it doesn't need to be actual textboxes or labels, just the representation of them, draw with text, rectangles, horizontal lines, etc.

Do I need a special library, framework, etc?

Comment: could you come up with a better title? Questions are meant to be as general as possible, ans while your question is kinda general, your title is non-descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [Piccolo 2D](http://www.piccolo2d.org/) framework.  I've used it for years for a few mapping and graph projects with good results.  It's flexible and could easily accommodate the picture you posted.